# Radeon HD 4650 fan continuously stopping and starting

Tags: graphics-card, fan, amd-radeon

I'm back at my family's house for the week for Thanksgiving, and my brother mentioned that there's a problem with their graphics card fan (which he's been solving by blowing an actual fan into the case). What I found is that the fan is constantly in a state of stopping and starting, with a frequency of 2-3 stops per second.

I should note that I think it stops, but I don't know if it comes to a complete halt, because it is a sudden stop and then it starts back up again that same instant. However it slows down enough that I can actually see the blades.

I have a feeling that this stopping/starting is happening only when the fan is set to run at higher speeds (when the card is hotter), because the fan seemed to run normally at a low speed for a while after I took out the card, looked it over, and reseated it. I initially thought that might have been it, but after a couple hours of running it was back to cutting out.

I haven't had a chance to test this hypothesis yet though. I've been trying to get something to control the fan speed, but for some reason CCC doesn't have the ATI Overdrive section, and I saw suggestions for RivaTuner but was having trouble getting it to work with Windows 7 x64 Home Premium, because Windows doesn't want to allow me to install unsigned drivers. So I'm kind of stuck on that right now. I'll turn the computer off and let it cool down in a little while to test it out, but it isn't exactly an optimal test.

I'm wondering if anyone has any knowledge with regard to the manually setting fan speeds, but more to the point, does anyone have experience with similar fan issues, and how did you resolve them (other than RMA or buy a new card)?